# Como llenar un datagridview con getProcess de c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Que tal me podrian orientar de como llenar un datagridview que tengo en asp.net

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" Width="646px">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="columna1" />
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="columna2" />
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="columna3" />
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="columna4" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

con un metodo de la clase GetProcesses en c# como este:

```
Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();

        foreach(Process theprocess in processlist){
        Console.WriteLine("Process: {0} ID: {1}", theprocess.ProcessName, theprocess.Id); 
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
```

para que lo que muestra en consola se llene en el datagridview, gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para mostrar en un `DataGridview` los datos de una lista puedes usar la propiedad [`DataSource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basedataboundcontrol.datasource(v=vs.110).aspx)

En tu caso podrías asignar directamente el resultado de `Process.GetProcesses()` aunque es preferible crear una clase intermedia con los datos a mostrar

El código sería algo como esto::

```
// Clase con la información que se necesita de un proceso
public class ProcessInfo
{
   public int Id { get; set; }     
   public string Name { get; set; }
}

// Evento de carga de la página
void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if(!IsPostBack)
   {
       // Obtener información de los procesos seleccionando los datos a mostrar
       // es necesario añadir un using System.Linq
       var processList = Process.GetProcesses().Select(p => new ProcessInfo
       {
          Id = p.Id,
          Name = p.ProcessName
       });

       // Asignar la lista de procesos a la Grid
       GridView1.DataSource = processList;
       GridView1.DataBind();
   }     
}
```

Este sería el HTML con el que mostrarías la información en el `GridView`

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" Width="646px">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField datafield="Id" HeaderText="Identificador" />
        <asp:BoundField datafield="Name" HeaderText="Nombre" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Gracias por responder @rsciriano, pero tengo problemas al mostrar los datos cuando se carga la pagina (no muestra errores en tiempo de compilacion) que podria ser?

Comment: Hola @matteo, ¿te muestra algún error al ejecutar la página? ¿Estás incluyendo el código C# correctamente en tu página (ya deberías tener un método Page_Load)? ¿Has intentado depurar poniendo un punto de ruptura en el Page_load? ¿Que versión de Visual Studio y .NET estás usando?

Comment: NO muestra errores, el codigo c# esta correctamente cargado ya que funciona con algunos otros metodos que se cargan a la pagina, utilizo la version .net framework 4.0 y de vs.net 2012

Comment: @matteo Prueba a llamar a `GridView1.DataBind();` justo después de establecer el valor de `GridView1.DataSource´

Comment: al invocar GridView1.DataBind();
me genera una excepcion..

    Property accessor 'Title' on object '_Default' threw the following exception:'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Comment: LA EXCEPCION ME APARECIA porque accidentalmente agregue la funcion ya mencionada en otro metodo duplicado, pero ya lo quite, sigue sin mostrar errores, 
por cierto anteriormente tampoco podia mostrar el gridview con datos estaticos posiblemente mi error es en la implementacion del mismo en la pagina asp?

Comment: @matteo debe ser algo que tienes en tu página porque he probado mi código (con el `DataBind()`) en una nueva página y a mí si me muestra la lista de procesos. Intenta depurar a ver si ves el problema, o empieza en una nueva página y ve agregando el código, ... podrían ser varias cosas

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39032/discussion-between-matteo-and-rsciriano).